# css - centering ul li in mobile

Tags: html, css

[image: This is image of results]

I want to center li in ul.
It looks centered but slightly not.
Left portion and Right portion is not exactly same.

How can I fix this problem?

```css
.test-box {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.test-ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.test-li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-box">
  <ul class="test-ul">
    <li class="test-li">real time</li>
    <li class="test-li">real time</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove padding-left from ```.test-ul```, which browser gives by default.

Comment: A browser sets some default style to a webpage just to ensure that the page looks good even if the developer did not give any styling to it, or if the styles are not loaded properly. A popular way to undo all the browser styling is using [CSS reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: [Massive duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=padding+left+ul+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

`<ul>` elements have left padding by default.

```
.test-ul
{
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
.test-box {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.test-ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.test-li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-box">
  <ul class="test-ul">
    <li class="test-li">real time</li>
    <li class="test-li">real time</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

vs

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it.. But is is a dupe anyway

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not good at english.. You mean it is not a legit way to do this?

Comment: It is legit, but there are [hundreds of identical questions and answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=padding+left+ul+site:stackoverflow.com) already on StackOverflow